# Php script to redirect to random sites from text

Tags: php

I need some help. I want to keep a url.txt file and inside it, bunch of URLs.
I am looking for Php script which will open those urls from that url.txt file randomly.

Please help. Thank you.

```
<?php
$urls = array(
"www.google.com",
"www.youtube.com",
"www.facebook.com"
);
$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)];
header("Location: http://$url");
?>
```

I tried this to redirect to random sites. But I want php to open the links saved in a separate .txt file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Like @Testing said, show us your code, where it fails, what errors you get etc.

Comment: "<?php
$urls = array(
"www.google.com",
"www.youtube.com",
"www.facebook.com"
);
$url = $urls[array_rand($urls)];
header("Location: http://$url");
?>"

I used this to redirect to random site. but I want it to open the urls saved in a text file. not in php script.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the size of the file read urls into an array and then randomly slect one and redirect from there.